# Plugin update failed - 'Installation failed: 504 Gateway Time-out 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.15.8' error message

Tags: plugins

Was using 'The Events Calendar' plugin on a website, plugin seemed to randomly delete itself and a php error message was shown.

Now when I try to re-install the plugin I'm getting an 'update failed' error message and the following text:

"Installation failed: 504 Gateway Time-out 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.15.8 "

When I go into FTP, the plugin folder still exists within the back-end. I've spent ages adding events onto the calendar before it broke.

How can I resolve this issue? Worried about deleting the folder as I don't want to lose the event data.

My site is www.wheatfen.org and webhost is Fasthosts (DO NOT use them as they are shocking).

Thanks.

[image: screenshot of error message]

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.